# When is componentWillReceiveProps called when using callbacks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm running into what looks like may be a race condition. Essentially, I have a login call, that when it fails will call a failure callback. This failure callback (callback A) in turn calls a function with it's own callback (callback B). What I'm seeing is the props in callback A have one value before callback B, but once callback B is executing, their value has changed to what I expected them to be. Let me illustrate this with some pseudo code:

```
login() {
    this.props.loginActions.login(this.failureCallback.bind(this))
}
```

In `loginActions`:

```
login(failureCallback) {
    return (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({
            types: [LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_SUCCESS]
            failure: () => failureCallback()
        });
    };
}
```

Then, back in the main screen, once we get a failure, I have something like this:

```
failureCallback() {
    // A
    const wasFail = this.props.isFail // This is false here, even though 
                                      // the LOGIN_FAILURE action is properly setting it to true

    if (wasFail) {
        // do stuff
    }

    functionWithCallback(() => {
        if (wasFail) {
            // B
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}

functionWithCallback(callback) {
    // C
    this.setState({...state, newStuffHere}, callback);
    // D
}
```

What I'm doing is placing a log at `mapStateToProps`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and then a log statement at `A`, `B`, and `C`. What I'm seeing is the following:

1. mapStateToProps called setting prop to correct value
2. log at A being called, showing the incorrect value
3. Log at C is called
4. Log at D is called
5. Map state to props called again with correct value
6. componentWillReceiveProps called with the correct value
7. Log at B called with correct value

   What it seems to me is going on is that at the time when the action is dispatched, React knows only about callback A. So, before giving my component new props, it calls callback A. Callback A then calls callback B. Once callback A has finished, componentWillReceiveProps is called, while callback B still hasn't been called. So by the time callback B is called, the component is now updated with the correct props.

Does this seem correct to anyone else? It's a somewhat complex issue I'm facing, and I've tried to illustrate it the best I can while removing the complexities.

I have one more point to make, the three types is part of a middleware we have to dispatch multiple actions at once, essentially if the request fails it will dispatch the action correctly, and if the request succeeds, it will correctly dispatch SUCCESS. From what I can tell, this is working, however, if the situation I've described above is not how React behaves, I can try to give more information on what our middleware is doing.

Comment: You action should NOT contain a failure property (https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action). Consider using promises to determine if the call failed.

Comment: I think this is largely complicated by trying to access values on `this`. It would be so much easier to reason about by simply passing arguments to the function as opposed to fiddling with weird class instance property access.

Comment: also calling setState inside the action flow is... wacky at best

Comment: To all above, changing the architecture of the code isn't really an option for us, this is a project with thousands of files being done in this way, and while I agree that there may be better ways around it, it's just too large of an effort to fix this one place -- it's a project I came onto after quite a bit of development had been done so many of these decisions are now set in stone -- although a callback would be one way to go about this, I am going to check into that -- I would still be interested in how React handles the above situation though